# Changing the attribute name of an input form based on how many ajax request have been done

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Lets say I need a condition to be true if it is every multiple of 10 + 3 and every multiple of 10 + 9. (i.e. 13, 23, 33, 43,..., 19, 29, 39, 49,...).  How would I go about doing that.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: what language? see also [fizz buzz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizz_buzz#Other_uses)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the [modulo operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation). Assuming `X` holds the number of AJAX requests, if `X mod 10 = 3` or `X mod 10 = 9` this condition is true.

---

In JavaScript there is no strict modulo operator but there is a [remainder operator (`%`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators) which performs nearly the same function as applied to positive integers. Therefore your condition would look like:

```
if ((X % 10 == 3) || (X % 10 == 9))
```

Comment: its all good but your code you typed out is different from your logic. Thanks!

Comment: @ddelnano Yes, yes it is. And it took me three more reads through to figure out what you meant. Sorry!